# Couldn't login after registration in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a case that I am registering a user with `wp_insert_user()` and logging in with `wp_signon()`. Registration is successful but when I use `wp_signon()`, I get error:

> 'Invalid username or password. Please try again!'.

Here are my efforts, I couldn't find the issue.

```
function wp_create_user_my($username, $password, $email = '', $fname, $lname) {
    $first_name = wp_slash($fname);
    $last_name = wp_slash($lname);
    $user_login = wp_slash($username);
    $user_email = wp_slash($email);
    $user_pass = $password;
    $userdata = compact('user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass','first_name','last_name');
    return wp_insert_user($userdata);
}
```

Here is code of `signon()`

```
$login_data['user_login'] = esc_attr($username);
$login_data['user_password'] = esc_attr($new_password);
$login_data['remember'] = true;
$user_verify = wp_signon($login_data, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

```
$login_data['user_login'] = esc_attr($username);
$login_data['user_password'] = esc_attr($new_password);
```

The `esc_attr` function encodes the `<, >, &, " and '` signs/symbols. If the user has any of those in their usernames or passwords, it's going to be different from what was originally stored/saved in the database, since what is passed to the compared against the database stored value is the escaped version of any or all of those characters.

I'd suggest you use the `wp_slash` function you used when inserting the user:

```
$login_data['user_login'] = wp_slash($username);
$login_data['user_password'] = wp_slash($new_password);
```

That way, what you get is consistent with what was inserted into the database.

Comment: Try to `var_dump` the values at the point of insertion (when creating a new user), and the values at the point of signon to see if they return same or different values. You could start troubleshooting from there.

Comment: I tried wp_signon() soon after successful registration, its working fine. but after some delay, in a separate call, its not working.

Comment: Ok, glad I could help.